# Identity function from Q to Q

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given that $f : Q \to Q$ is a homomorphism and $f(\frac ba) = f(\frac ab)^{-1}$, how can I show that $f$ must be the identity function?

I know that the only homomorphism from $Q$ to $Q$ is indeed the identity function, but specifically I need to derive it from the fact above.

I've started by saying that $f(\frac ab) = \frac cd$, and I want to show $\frac cd = \frac ab$. I've gotten as far as saying that since $f(\frac ab) = \frac cd$, $f(\frac ba) = \frac dc$, but I'm not sure where to go from there. I've tried multiplying the two equations only to learn that $f(\frac 11) = \frac 11$ (as is true of all homomorphisms of this nature, which leads me nowhere).

Does anyone have any hints as to how I should approach this?

Comment: Is this a homomorphism of Q a additive group, Q a multiplicative group, or Q a field?

Comment: $f$ is a ring homomorphism. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes. In the case of groups, it need not be the identity function.

Answer (score 2):

From the additive structure, the only homomorphisms are of the form $f(x) = kx$, where $k$ is a rational number. (Standard induction proof).

From the multiplicative structure, since $f(x^2) = f(x) f(x) $, thus $ k = k^2$, which gives us $k= 0$ or 1.

But if $k=0$, then $f(\frac{a}{b} ) ^{-1}$ doesn't make sense.

Hence $k=1$ and we are done.

---

Note: If we only had the multiplicative structure, $f(x) = x^n$ is a possible solution.